# Show custom indexer in debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have sample indexer like ths:

```
public byte this[long pIndex]
{
    get
    {
        // return something
    }
}
```

How to tell Visual Studio to display all elements from this indexer in debugger? And how to tell about pIndex range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `IEnumberable` interface in your class. Debugger can use it to get all the items and display them the same way it displays linq expression results.

If you want to see the single element, you can add a watch expression `this[123]`

Comment: you have to use the type of the index in the debugger. For example if the have: public enum UnitEnum { None = 0, Milimeter, Inch, KiloGram, Pound, Celsius, Fahrenheit, } and double this[UnitEnum key] : Write in the debugger for example: this[UnitEnum.Fahrenheit]

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Debugger Display Attribute, as described here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163974.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx

Try doing something like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{this[0]}")]
public byte this[long pIndex]
{
    get
    {
        // return something
    }
}
```

Comment: @zgnilec I updated the answer with a suggestion. Hopefully it works.

Comment: It's not working. How debbuger will know about valid pIndex values? I found only IList implementations in web. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: @zgnilec it doesn't know about valid values, but why does it need to? Or are you looking to have the debugger show all the items in the list? If so, implement IEnumerable as the other answer shows. If that's not the case, please update your question to indicate what kind of display you want in the debugger.

Comment: Ok, looks like IEnumerable is the only way.